# Python subprocess picking wrong binary

Tags: python, subprocess

I have an issue with python `subprocess.Popen` calling the executable from the environment `PATH` even though I specify the absolute path to the binary I want to call.

**Details:**

I have a conda binary installed under `/opt/apps/some_app/bin/conda` and I want my python script to install `boto` in it. The relevant snippet of code is

```
logging.debug('Installing boto')
conda_bin = os.path.join('/opt/apps/', 'some_app', 'bin', 'conda')
args = [conda_bin, 'install', '--yes', 'boto==2.37.0']
logging.debug('Executing: %s', ' '.join(args))
process = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
output, _ = process.communicate()
print output
```

The output of the snippet is

```
DEBUG root:_install_environment(453): Installing boto
DEBUG root:_install_environment(455): Executing: /opt/apps/some_app/bin/conda install --yes boto==2.37.0
Fetching package metadata .....
Solving package specifications: ..........

Package plan for installation in environment /home/user/miniconda:
...
```

which suggests `Popen` is picking the system conda available at `/home/user/miniconda/bin` instead of the one specified through absolute path in the code.

If I run the command manually everything works as expected.

Any suggestion on what might be causing this behaviour?

Comment: you may want to wrap/test your Popen command with shell wrapper displaying environment as well. It's definitely about PATH or PWD. Code seems to be correct

Comment: Yeah I tried explicitly setting the environment path passed to `Popen` to exclude `/home/user/miniconda/bin` but didn't change. I also tried changing the command to `./conda` and running from `/opt/apps/some_app/bin/` as `cwd` but didn't fix it either.

Comment: and, replacing your callee (executable you want to launch) with shell script dumping environment and arguments? Being at your place, I'd went this road debugging your issue